# Running a script inside a docker container using shell script from host

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy, docker, containers

I am new to Docker technology,I am trying to create a shell script on my host to **clear caches** and to **deploy my static content** in Magento 2 inside my apach containe.
to access to my apach container i use this command :

```
docker-compose exec --user www-data apache bash
```

and i created my script shell in the my project root on my host.
my question is how can i run my shell script outside my apache container to execute this command:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME php /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f